# Java - Same class in build classpath and runtime classpath priority

Tags: java, build, runtime, classpath

I'm not a Java expert, and I have a doubt about class resolution in case of conflict. Consider the scenario where I have two jar files `external-library-0.0.1`, `external-library-0.0.2` both having a class `Foo`.

If I build with only `external-library-0.0.1.jar` in the build classpath, and then I add `external-library-0.0.2.jar` in the runtime classpath, which class `Foo` will be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one which is on the runtime classpath will be used.
The other one is simply not known to the JVM at runtime.

If there're any discrepancies (e.g. a method does not exist), you'll get an error at runtime.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Infact I had a runtime error, and my supposition was that I have some conflicts due to an error in my `pom.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

From the programmer point of view, assume **random**. Never put more than one definition of the same class on the classpath, neither at compile time nor at runtime.

One can point that sometimes there are tools that try to offer guarantees about load order, but rely on it makes your application inherently fragile, and this kind of bug is really hard to fix when you need to.